# Ul li expanded jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this, actually how to make the expanded box is always below the row of clicked li, i mean if the second li clicked it will expand below the first row, or after 4th li and so on, how to gain it, also, when i click the first li, expanded open, but if i click the second li it will close, how to make like i click the first li, its open, when i click the other li, it will close first and then open, thanks

html :

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>  
      <li>
       <a href="#"><img src="http://s13.postimg.org/8caamw1af/image4.jpg" /></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#"><img src="http://s13.postimg.org/8caamw1af/image4.jpg" /></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#"><img src="http://s13.postimg.org/8caamw1af/image4.jpg" /></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#"><img src="http://s13.postimg.org/8caamw1af/image4.jpg" /></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#"><img src="http://s13.postimg.org/8caamw1af/image4.jpg" /></a>
      </li>

     <li class="expanded">
     <div>abc</div>
     </li>

    </ul>
   </div>
```

jquery :

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 

    var expanded = false;

    $( ".container ul li" ).click(function(e) {
        if (expanded) {
            $( ".expanded" ).slideUp("slow");
            expanded = false;
        }
        else {
            $( ".expanded" ).slideDown("slow");
            expanded= true;
        }
    }); 
});
```

css :

```
body, ul {   
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;  
   }
   .container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
   }
   li {
    width: 23%;
    margin: 10px 1% 0 1%;
    float: left;
    list-style: none outside none;

   }
   li img {
    width: 100%;
   }

   .expanded {
    position: relative;   
    display: none;
    background: #ccc;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    }
```

FIDDLE [>>](http://jsfiddle.net/3a7pjeb9/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/buxdhjyh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an `li.expanded` after each row you want to display like in the fiddle I have attached.

Then use the following code to toggle the li

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $(".container ul li").click(function (e) {
          var $closest_li = $(this).nextAll('.expanded').first();
          var needs_to_close = $closest_li.is(':visible');
          $(".expanded").slideUp("slow", function(){
              if(!needs_to_close){$closest_li.slideDown('slow');}
          });
      });
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3a7pjeb9/8/

Edited to make it close when clicked for a second time rather than retoggle

Comment: the problem was in the responsive, and echo on php, could use inserAfter function ? each 4 li, much thanks, also the first row and second row had different slide behaviour @DGS

Answer (score 0):

try this

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3a7pjeb9/6/)

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 

    var expanded = false;

    $( ".container ul li" ).click(function(e) {
        if ($(this).next().hasClass("expanded")) {
            $( ".expanded" ).slideUp("slow");
            $( ".expanded" ).remove();
        }
        else {
            $( ".expanded" ).slideUp("slow");
            $( ".expanded" ).remove();
         var test = '<li class="expanded"> <div>abc</div> </li>';
            $(this).after(test);
            $( ".expanded" ).slideDown("slow");

        }
    }); 
});
```